# Django sites framework and Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Just wanted to ask if this was an 'acceptable' use of the django sites framework and heroku - and if there would be any trouble running the two sites:

Main differences between sites will be templates, and some objects only published to one or other (or both) sites - notably users should be able to use both sites using their single account.

- I have my one codebase. Any change in my settings.py file is dealt
  with by using heroku config variables.
- I set up database that can be shared (either on an EC2 or using
  Heroku dedicated dbs)
- I git push my code to two different Heroku Apps

Hey presto - one codebase, two running instances of Django, two separate sites.

Any issues with that?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I have the same question or desires.  Did you ever get this working?  Could you post your answer here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into great depth to answer this question in another thread, you can see my answer here: [Multiple Django sites with shared codebase and DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376455/multiple-django-sites-with-shared-codebase-and-db/11803686#11803686)

The short answer is **NO**, don't use the sites framework, use git branches.