# Django deploy app multiple domains best practices

Tags: django, duplicates, multisite

i have developed an app that controls clients for a store.this app is deployed in heroku and now i want to deploy it for more than one store

The app may suffer little changes from store to store but basicaly it's going to be the same. Each store has their own db and administration site.

I've been looking into multisite solution but i think it doesn't fit for what i need. Is it better to just clon the app and deploy them as different apps? Make appropiate changes to each store and maintain both apps? Isn't an efficient way of doing this?.

In case no modifications are needed, by just adding more than one remote and deploying, is that a good practice? How do you deal with diferent settings.py?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this very helpful, even this talks about sharing the db, the main idea looks great:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803686/4469888